# Is there a max number of arrows you can have?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I'm always buying any arrow I can find, so I never run out.

I wonder... will I, at some point, reach a maximum number of arrows per category?

Comment: As answered before ( http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/303606/179563 )there is a manipulation of the availability of some items, arrows in particular. When you have over a certain amount, they will no longer restock at shops. Amiibo drops and some grinding can add up though. I have reached over 400 myself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The maximum number of arrows you can carry is 999 each