# What is the max stack I can get of an item?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

If I was to collect apple over apple over apple, would I, at some time, hit a max stack of that item? Like you can't carry more apples?

If yes, at what is that max?

Comment: I saw somewhere it is 999, but I can't say for sure. Edit: Oh, I confused this with the max number of arrows. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304086/is-there-a-max-number-of-arrows-you-can-have

Comment: I was just wondering this as well. I just started playing a couple days ago and have become an apple hoarder (I think I'm at around 65), started wondering if I'd be prevented from getting more (or make a second stack) at 99.

Comment: Can confirm that i had more than 99 in a material stack at some point, so limit isnt 99

Comment: Going by anecdotal evidence in [this Zelda subreddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/626z4b/real_100_completion_spoilers/), it appears to be 99999 for materials.

Comment: I found in the Zeldapedia it states 999 - but it says [verification needed] at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty positive it is around 999 for arrows, and maybe 999 or more for materials. probably to 9999 or even up to 99999. Its probably the width of the item box, which would be around 99999.

Comment: Wood, at the very least, goes to exactly  999

Answer (score 1):

The limit for materials seems to be 999 as well.

To verify this (at your own risk, this may cause memory issues), activate [the dupe glitch](https://www.reddit.com/r/speedrun/comments/6nxkx8/breath_of_the_wild_dupe_glitch_megathread/), then topple over a dead guardian (the kind that can be searched for an ancient material).